# Duplicar registro por su campo fecha dependiendo del mes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero hacer una consulta o una vista en sql donde tengo dos tablas: la primera es una tabla llamada *DocumentosPeriodicos* en la cual tengo dados de alta varios documentos, los cuales pongo que se dupliquen por mes, semana o año.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para duplicar ese registro si, por ejemplo, la fecha del primer documento es el 01 enero 2022 y necesito que se duplique el 01 de cada mes, así sucesivamente?

Comment: Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] para mostrar lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Evita además agregar ruido a la pregunta: a más _ayudaaaaaaaaaaa_ que pidas, menos te ayudarán :)

Comment: Buen día, tendrás la estructura de esa tabla? para ver los campos y tener un poco mas de visión en lo que requieres.

Answer (score 0):

Para duplicar filas en SQL, lo ideal es utilizar una tabla de números. Una tabla de números (o *tally table* en inglés) es simplemente una tabla con una sola columna de números consecutivos. La tabla puede ser física, temporal o creada solo en memoria. Para generar una tabla en memoria podemos hacerlo con CTEs en cascada.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS( -- 10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( -- 10 x 10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( -- 100 x 100 = 10,000 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS( -- Asignamos números consecutivos a las filas
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT n
FROM cteTally;
```

A este código básico, solo necesitamos agregar un poco de lógica para limitar el número de filas y hacer los cálculos de fechas. Además lo convertimos en una función para poder reutilizar el código más fácilmente.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RepeticionesFechas(
    @Fecha         date,
    @Periodo       varchar(10),
    @Repeticiones  int
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN

WITH 
E(n) AS( -- 10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( -- 10 x 10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( -- 100 x 100 = 10,000 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS( -- Asignamos números consecutivos a las filas
    SELECT TOP( @Repeticiones) 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT CASE WHEN @Periodo = 'Semana' THEN DATEADD( WK, n, @Fecha)
            WHEN @Periodo = 'Mes'    THEN DATEADD( MM, n, @Fecha)
            WHEN @Periodo = 'Año'    THEN DATEADD( YY, n, @Fecha)
            END AS Fecha
FROM cteTally;
```

Ya teniendo la función, solo la incluimos al momento de consultar la tabla mediante la instrucción `APPLY`. Dejo aparte un ejemplo con datos de prueba.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DocumentosPeriodicos(
    DocID           int,
    FechaInicial    date,
    Periodo         varchar(10),
    Repeticiones    int);

INSERT INTO dbo.DocumentosPeriodicos
VALUES( 1, '20220101', 'Semana', 52),
      ( 2, '20220101', 'Mes'   , 12),
      ( 3, '20220101', 'Año'   , 10);

SELECT *
FROM dbo.DocumentosPeriodicos dp
CROSS APPLY dbo.RepeticionesFechas( dp.FechaInicial, dp.Periodo, dp.Repeticiones) rf;
```